# Application only works correctly if I have messagebox in the code

Tags: c#

I have a button event in which generates some random numbers based upon the number typed into a textbox (for example, if I type 5, it should generate 5 different random numbers). When I type in a number into the textbox, and click the btnGenerateScores button, it generates a single number and puts that  number in the listbox 5 times (or however many times based upon the number in the textbox). This behavior is not correct, it should generate 5 different numbers and list each in the listbox. If I put a MessageBox.Show (I was using it for debugging) command anywhere in the code block, it works correctly. Commenting out the MessageBox.show breaks the code. Does anyone see any reason why it would not work correctly when I don't show the message box? The code is below:

```
private void btnGenerateScores_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                strInput = txtInputNumber.Text;
                intRandCount = Convert.ToInt16(strInput);
                scoresArray = new int[intRandCount];
                intArrayCount = scoresArray.Length;
            btnGenerateScores.Enabled = false;
            // Loop to generate random number
            for (intRndCount = 0; intRndCount < intRandCount; intRndCount++)
            {
                GetRand(intRandCount);
                scoresArray[intCount] = intRandomNum;
                intGenRandom = intRandomNum;

                intArrScores = scoresArray[intCount];
                lstRdmScores.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(intArrScores));
                insertionSortArray = new int[intArrayCount];
                Array.Copy(scoresArray, insertionSortArray, intArrayCount);

                // Instantiate an instance of the class
                arraySort mySort = new arraySort();

                // Get the number of elements to store in the array                    
                string s = Convert.ToString(intCount);
                mySort.x = Int16.Parse(s);                  

                // Get array elements
                for (int i = 0; i < mySort.x; i++)
                {
                    intInsertionSort = insertionSortArray[intCount];
                    string s1 = Convert.ToString(intInsertionSort);
                    mySort.a[i] = Int16.Parse(s1);

                }

                // Sort the array and display in the second list box
                mySort.sortArray();
                intSortScores = insertionSortArray[intCount];
                lstSortScores.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(intSortScores));

// This is the the MessageBox.Show command in question:

    MessageBox.Show("The random number generated is: "); //+ Convert.ToString(intGenRandom));
            }
        }
```

ignore the fact that the array does not sort correctly,  I will get to that later. I want to work on one thing at a time.
I am using VS 2013 and the code was originally created in VS 2005.

Comment: One suggestion: You should use more distinct names for variables. `intRandCount` is too similar to `intRndCount`

Comment: That doesn't appear to show the entire code (ie. where is intRandomNum assigned?). In any case the problem sounds like it *might* be due to creating a new Random object .. Make sure the Random object is created only *once* and reused; Random objects created too-close-together - which could be if the message box was removed - may produce the same output.

Comment: Also you are missing `int` before the `intRndCount` in the for loop.

Comment: This question needs some work - this code is nowhere near complete enough.  We cannot see any of the variable declarations - this is very important.  We cannot see the definition of `GetRand` - this is very important.  We can't see the class definition of `arraySort` - this is very important.  We need to be able to test the code you have provided - to do this the code must be complete and it must demonstrate the problem.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement, and view the source, I rewrite the app for short:

```
    private void btnGenerateScores_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int genTimes;
        if (Int32.TryParse(txtInputNumber.Text, out genTimes))
        {
            var ints = new List<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < genTimes; i++)
            {
                var r = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
                var rInt = r.Next(0, int.MaxValue); //for ints
                ints.Add(rInt);
            }

            var copyInts = ints.ToList();
            copyInts.AddRange(this.listBox1.Items.Cast<int>());
            copyInts = copyInts.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
            this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
            this.listBox1.Items.AddRange(copyInts.Cast<object>().ToArray());
            MessageBox.Show("The random number generated is: " + String.Join(",", ints));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

[image]

Comment: `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());` is a very very odd choice. Why not just create the `Random` outside of the click event and just reference the single instance?

Comment: I give it out the function. And it works. Let go ahead.

Comment: This does not answer the question.